# How to deal with RESTKit Reachability Assertion Failure

Tags: ios, restkit

When setting up a RKObjectManager the follow can occur:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[RKReachabilityObserver validateIntrospection]
```

Referenced here on Google Groups:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/restkit/JQ4I6MZrVyc%5B1-25%5D

Answer (score 0):

The answer, at least in my scenario:

Once the RKObjectManager has it's baseURL provided during setup, like this:

```
RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:MY_BASE_API_URL];
```

Directly replacing the underlying RKClient later on, like this:

```
manager.client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MY_BASE_API_URL]];
```

will cause this error:

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[RKReachabilityObserver validateIntrospection]
```

**So, once the top level RKObjectManager is setup, don't try to replace the RKClient.**

Seems like there are a few variants to the problem, anyone else want to weigh in?